# Помогите разобраться с API C# MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, windows, api, icq

Здравствуйте нужна помощь, не могу понять как отправить несколько значений и multipart в C#

```
public void SendMessage(string chat_id, string message, string dir_file)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var stream = new FileStream(dir_file, FileMode.Open);
            string response = null;
            using (var contents = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                contents.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");
                contents.Add(new StringContent(chat_id), "chatId");
                contents.Add(new StringContent(""), "caption");
                contents.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file");

                response = client.PostAsync(uri_send_file_message, contents).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
```

Пытаюсь организовать загрузку файла на ICQ API https://icq.com/botapi/?lang=ru там получается сначала отправляю файл с параметрами, получаю ID файла и потом отправляю его в тот чат, который нужен.... но вот что-то multipart не дается...

Comment: У вас контент идёт как ключ... А ключ как контент. Поменяйте из местами

Comment: `contents.Add(new StringContent("token"), token);
contents.Add(new StringContent("chatId"), chat_id);
contents.Add(new StringContent("caption"), "as");
 contents.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file");`

Comment: так тоже не работает, или я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: мне api отвечает что требуемый параметр не найден....

Comment: подсказка: 1) `HttpClient`, `HttpContent`, `HttpRequestMessage` и `HttpResponseMessage` являются `IDisposable` - [Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects). Так как вы игнорируете сей факт, вы можете получить непредсказуемое поведение там, где не ожидаете. 2) `HttpClient` лучше создавать один раз вне метода и переиспользовать `private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient()`.

Comment: 3) `public void SendMessage` замените на `public async Task SendMessageAsync` и строчку `response = client.PostAsync...` замените на 2 строчки `using responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(uri_send_file_message, contents); response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. Тогда приложение не будет зависать, пока идет запрос. В обработчике события `void` поменяйте на `async void` и вызывайте свой метод как `await SendMessageAsync(...)`. [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: `FileStream` кстати тоже `IDisposable`. Если примете эти советы к сведению и обновите код в вопросе, я может быть еще что-то смогу подсказать. А пока я вижу в коде больше проблем, чем вы, и нерабочий запрос - последняя из них, которую стоит решать.

Comment: Я не понимаю.... мне бы на пальцах...

Comment: Самое странное что для телеграм отправка файла работает, но для ICQ тот же самый код не работает, хотя что там мультипарт что там..... очень странно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать не HttpClient c MultipartFormDataContent а для ICQ используется WebClient.